# Python 3.3 - Generate odd numbers

Tags: python

Ok so I've gotten stuck on this program I'm working on. I know how to make a program spit out random numbers... cool. However, I want it to only spit out odd numbers and have no idea how to do that. Here's what I've got so far... any ideas on this one?

```
import random

myfile = open('numbers.txt', 'w')
odd = 0

for count in range(3,8,1):
file_size = random.randint(5,19)
myfile.write(str(file_size) + '\n')


myfile.close()
```

Comment: `random.choice(range(5,19,2))` would be my first guess. Might need to do `random.choice(list(range(5,19,2)))`

Comment: @NightShadeQueen `random.choice(range(5,19,2))` would work alone

Comment: You want random odd numbers?

Comment: Yep I want random odd numbers....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the power of maths:

```
import random
def rand_with_parity(start, end):
    return 2*random.randint(0, (end-start)//2)+start

myfile = open('numbers.txt', 'w')

for count in range(3,8,1):
   file_size = rand_with_parity(5,19)
   myfile.write(str(file_size) + '\n')


myfile.close()
```

The `rand_with_parity(a,b)` function will return random numbers in the range [a,b] that are even if a and b are even, or odd if a and b are odd.